The distribution of X + Y - floor(X + Y) where X and Y are independent and uniformly distributed over (0, 1)
I'm having trouble understanding the following discussion on the distribution of $X + Y - \lfloor X + Y\rfloor$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent and uniformly distributed over $(0, 1)$:
If $t \in [0, 1]$, then $F_{X + Y - \lfloor X + Y\rfloor}(t) = P(0 \leq X + Y \leq t) + P(1 \leq X + Y \leq t + 1) = \int_0^t u\mathrm{d}u + \int_1^{t + 1} 2 - u\mathrm{d}u$.
How do you work out the density of $X + Y$ to be $2 - u$ between $1$ and $t + 1$?

Do you know the distribution for $U=X+Y$ under these conditions? If you do, that should make the application to the present case obvious.
